# MVC inquiry, controller checks condition, stay on current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

so a controller has to return a view. 
I'm wondering what would be a professional approach in this scenario?

controller checks condition, if true, proceeds, if false, pops up a message, stays on current page? Thanks.

So it is a "delete" action link on the "index" view, when I click on the "delete" link, I check the condition on "delete" controller, if false, I want to stay on "index" view. But the controller has to return something.

I redirected to the current page ("index" view), it flashes, and the browser embedded message box is rather rough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a controller method you can return either a View, a File, a PartialView, a Json or even more.
If you want the page stay there without refreshing, my suggestion is to use Ajax to submit your request and then return a Json.

In the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "YourControllerClass")/?parameter=dummy',
            success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.message);
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string parameter)
    {
        //... do some stuff

        return Json(new { message = "your return message..." }, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm inexperienced in this. So the script should be placed on the current page's view. And the action "DoSomething" leads to "DoSomething" view. I guess it will have a URL as ~/DoSomething/parameter, which is the same as url: '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "YourControllerClass")/?parameter=dummy' correct? But I can't see how it will stay on the current page. Doesn't it go to DoSomething's view rather than staying on the current page? Thanks.

Comment: The Ajax call is executed in background and the current page (which execute the javascript) is not reloaded. Returning a Json from the controller will 'feed' back the Ajax call (the 'success' parameter of the ajax call); within the success function you can do something (for example an alert message) based on the returned data.